# WP:Fetch record using custom query object technique

Tags: mysql, wordpress

For custom query in wordpress 3.3.1 I am using

```
$s = $_GET['s'];
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%".$s."%' GROUP BY post_title");
```

and it returns object array

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post_title] => Charles Murray does it again ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [post_title] => The education crisis myth ) )
```

but how could I fetch post_title..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oop I just made a mistake.
One should traverse an object array like:

```
echo $myrows->post_title;
```

or in more detail

```
$post_id = '36';
$post = get_post($post_id);
echo $title = $post->post_title;
```